# add bounce effect to countdown timer using jquery

Tags: jquery, countdown, bounce

I create simple countdown timer for my coming soon page using jquery.countdown

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
  var endDate = $('.counter').attr('timer');

  $('.counter .row').countdown({
    date: endDate,
    render: function(data) {
      var element = this.el;
      $(".days .count-round", element).html("<span class='text-center'>"  + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 2) + " <p> Days</p></span> ");
      $(".hours .count-round", element).html("<span class='text-center'>"  + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <p> Hours</p></span> ");
      $(".min .count-round", element).html("<span class='text-center'>"  + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <p> Minutes</p></span> ");
      $(".sec .count-round", element).html("<span class='text-center'>"  + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <p> Seconds</p></span> ");
    }
  });
});
```

Now I tried to add bounce effect to days, hours, minutes and seconds when change

this is bounce effect code

```
$('.count-round').effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);
```

Can anybody can help me?

Comment: It could be better if you paste your code on fiddle.

Comment: i tried to paste my code on fiddle but it`s not work

Comment: paste  your fiddle link

Comment: here is a demo page in codepen [link](http://codepen.io/EadHassan/pen/avbrmq)[link]